# Double dot product of two tensors

Tags: matlab, tensor-products, tensors

I have a problem that makes me very confused...

I have two tensors that must be multiply.
A is second order tensor and B is fourth order tensor.
I know when multiplying two tensor with double dot product (:) that means inner product, the order of result will be decrease two times. So now we must have a second order tensor for result.
but when I write this code in Matlab it has an error: **Matrix dimensions must agree.**
So how can I solve this problem?
Please Help me if you know anything about this.
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: could you give a little more detail on the type of tensors you consider and perhaps the code you tried. Someone else may be able to help you better once that is posted.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your general idea. Let me introduce some notation, let $T_{ij}$ be the components of the type $(2,0)$ tensor and $S^{ijkl}$ be the components of the type $(0,4)$ tensor. We can contract these as follows:
$$ T_{ij}S^{ijkl} = T_{11}S^{11kl}+ \cdots + T_{nn}S^{nnkl} $$
assuming this is over an $n$-dimensional space. As you can see the resulting tensor is rank $(0,2)$ since it has two free contravariant indices. I'm not sure this helps, but perhaps some of the words I use here will help you locate the desired Matlab code.

Comment: @Sarasky so you figured out the problem?